# How do I use Pytorch's NLLLoss with count data?

Tags: model, integer, pytorch

I have a model where I'm trying to predict with integer data, where an example of an expected output would be [40]. How do I use nn.PoissonNLLLoss to do this? Setting log_input=False slowly decreases my loss below 0.